# Lua for loop does not do all iterations

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, iteration

I am new to lua, and i am using it to automate some tasks in the simulation program femm. In my script i have this type of for loop:

```
for i=0.1,0.3,0.1
do
  print(i)
end
```

The problem is it only iterates from 0.1 to 0.2(it does not enter i=0.3).I tried with other values (for example from 0.1 to 0.4) and it works properly. Why does this strange behaviour happen? Is this a floating point number problem?

Comment: 0.3 may be not equal to 0.3

Comment: Is this because it is not declared as an integer(i have not used lua before)? Should i use only integer values for the loop variable?

Comment: Try `i=0.1, 0.3+1e-9, 0.1`

Comment: it sounds like you [may need a primer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) in floating point operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because adding 0.1 to 0.1 three times produces a number that is slightly greater than 0.3. Hence the loop stops before reaching your target end number.

This is the danger of using floating point values for loop iteration. Rewrite the loop in integers instead, and perform a division to get your required number:

```
for j = 1,3
do
    i = j/10
    print(i)
end
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/uAZ3of)